# Acender e apagar conteúdo do background com animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Queria fazer um efeito com o *animation* ou *transition* do CSS3 que quando o quadrado vermelho passar, o fundo aparecesse (o background amarelo com os textos) e apagasse logo em seguida assim que o quadrado vermelho terminasse de passar.

Abaixo está o máximo que consegui fazer, eu não consegui finalizar este efeito de jeito nenhum. Isso é possível? Desde já agradeço!

Coloquei um efeito no fundo utilizando o evento hover do mouse, quero este mesmo efeito, mas não com o mouse e sim com o quadrado vermelho passando.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>  
    <style>
 #yellow {
         background-color: yellow;
        }
    
        #shadow {
          background-color: black;
          width: 100%;
          height: 2048px;
          position:absolute; 
          left:1px; 
          top:1px;
          transition: all 3s ease;
        }

        #shadow:hover {
          opacity: 0;
        }

        #square {
          margin-top: 10px;
          width: 20px;
          height: 20px;
          background: red;
          position: relative;
          -webkit-animation: mymove 10s infinite; 
       }

        @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
            from {left: 0px;}
            to {left: 600px;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="yellow">
 <h1>Estou aqui!</h1><br><br>
    <h4>Texto teste</h4>
 
    <div id="shadow"></div>
    <div id="square"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo, mas não sei a intensidade nem o tempo que você vai querer, então para regular da forma que você desejar, você precisa regular somente estes valores:

*ease* - O tempo da animação

*normal* - Quando a animação vai começar

*fadein* - Intensidade do efeito fade

> ```
> animation:10s ease 0s normal forwards 25 fadein;
>
> -webkit-animation:10s ease 0s normal forwards 25 fadein;
> ```

Aqui ele começa com 100% da *opacity* a animação, no meio ela fica com 0% e no final 100% novamente, e como o tempo total da animação e 10 segundo (10s ease), que é o mesmo tempo do *square* então acontece a animação da forma ao qual você explicou.

> ```
> 0% { opacity:1; }
> 50% { opacity:0; }
> 100% { opacity:1; }
> ```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>  
    <style>
      #yellow {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
      #shadow {
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2048px;
        position:absolute; 
        left:1px; 
        top:1px;
        opacity:1;
      }
      #shadow {
        animation:10s ease 0s normal forwards 25 fadein;
        -webkit-animation:10s ease 0s normal forwards 25 fadein;
      }
      @keyframes fadein{from{opacity:0}
        0% { opacity:1; }
        50% { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:1; }
      }    
      @-webkit-keyframes fadein{from{opacity:0}
        0% { opacity:1; }
        50% { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:1; }
      }
      #square {
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: red;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: mymove 10s infinite; 
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
        from {left: 0px;}
        to {left: 600px;}
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body id="yellow">
    <h1>Estou aqui!</h1><br><br>
    <h4>Texto teste</h4>

    <div id="shadow"></div>
    <div id="square"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, uma dúvida, caso fosse um loop infinito e esse quadrado ficasse girando em círculos com uma determinada circunferência, ou até mesmo em reta infinita, seria possível fazer com que se vá apagando por onde ele passou e ilumine somente onde ele está? Obrigado por enquanto, é quase isso mesmo, não me expressei corretamente.

Comment: Você deve conseguir fazer este efeito de circulo com alguma imagem, veja esta responta, acredito que vai ajudar bastante: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286550/transparent-hollow-or-cut-out-circle

Comment: Consegui dar um jeito aqui. Obrigado!